# What's the cause of error Type 'AnimationStyleMetadata' has no properties in common with type 'AnimationOptions' on style method in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

In Angular 4.4.7, on a component Within the animation property declaration:

```
`animations: [
    trigger("expand", [
      state(
        "close",
        style({
          opacity: 0,
          display: "none",
          height: 0,
        })
      ),
      state(
        "open",
        style({
          display: "block",
          opacity: 1,
        })
      ),
      transition(
        "close => open",
        animate("0.3s ease-in-out"),
        style({ overflow: "hidden", position: "relative", height: "*" })
      ),
      transition(
        "open => close",
        animate("0.3s ease-in-out"),
        style({ overflow: "hidden", position: "relative", height: "*" })
      ),
    ]),
  ]`
```

An error happens on this line:

```
style({ overflow: "hidden", position: "relative", height: "*" })
```

The error being:

```
Type 'AnimationStyleMetadata' has no properties in common with type 'AnimationOptions'.ts(2559)
(property) overflow: string
```

[image]

This code was working for the previous developer, but VS code shows an error for me. I want to clear this error before moving on to upgrade the project from `4.4.7` to ver. 5.

The style type description says type `AnimationStyleMetadata`:

```
`(alias) style(tokens: "*" | {
    [key: string]: string | number;
} | ("*" | {
    [key: string]: string | number;
})[]): AnimationStyleMetadata`
```

I'm unsure why this error is trying to associate the style props to `AnimationOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by added [] around the arrray of  AnimationMetadata properties

```
 transition("open => close", [
        animate("0.3s ease-in-out"),
        style({ overflow: "hidden", position: "relative", height: "*" }),
      ]),
```